# How did the Cassiopeia A Supernova go unobserved?

Tags: supernova, dust

The Cassiopeia A was caused by a Supernova estimated to have taken place around the late 17th century. The Remnant's declination means that it would be Circumpolar for anyone north of 30N, and it's further from the Galactic core then our solar system, which is important because the interstellar dust gets denser as you get nearer to the core, and less dense as you move away.

Comment: Wikipeida deals with this, did you read the article?

Comment: @JamesK No [Wikipedia does not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassiopeia_A#Possible_observations) deal with "How did the Cassiopeia A Supernova go unobserved?" at all. There's only a dry list of some possible observations. This question requires some work to answer, and it might not be easy. (+1) and **voting to leave open** to allow others in the community an opportunity to answer. Remember close votes block answers.

Comment: "Its likely omission in records is probably due to interstellar dust absorbing optical wavelength radiation before it reached Earth, although it is possible that it was recorded as a sixth magnitude star 3 Cassiopeiae by John Flamsteed. "  That seems to answer the question.